# ImportError: cannot import name 'tqdm' from 'conda._vendor.tqdm' (unknown location)

Tags: python, anaconda, tqdm

Hello I am using mac actually when I searched analytics in finder I removed some folders (I thought they are useless :) after that when I type conda update or such I am getting those errors and further more.

I am keeping exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nunemunthalashiva/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/nunemunthalashiva/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 151, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "/Users/nunemunthalashiva/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .common.io import dashlist, timeout
  File "/Users/nunemunthalashiva/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .._vendor.tqdm import tqdm
ImportError: cannot import name 'tqdm' from 'conda._vendor.tqdm' (unknown location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with some libraries that are required to preform some basic operation later in python such as update or install libraries. I think you removed those python libraries that are required to update/used in other ....to remove these error you have to add/restore those libraries or reinstall python.

Comment: Yeah I know re installing python is not at all a good idea :) and obviously my question is specific to conda and not to python actually I surfed the whole web I hadn't found answer so I just removed conda and again installed it :) I know its a bad way but I had no option